# ImageView ScaleType vs drawable folders

Tags: android, image, drawable, scaling, image-scaling

I thought that the purpose of the different drawable folders (e.g. `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`) is to avoid unnecessary rescalings in order to save resources.

However, if I want to put an image into an `ImageView`, I have to choose an appropriate `ScaleType` to show the image correctly.

According to documentation:

> center
>
> Displays the image centered in the view with no scaling.
>
> centerCrop
>
> Scales the image such that both the x and y dimensions are greater
>   than or equal to the view, while maintaining the image aspect ratio;
>   crops any part of the image that exceeds the size of the view; centers
>   the image in the view.
>
> centerInside
>
> Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image
>   aspect ratio. If the image is already smaller than the view, then this
>   is the same as center.
>
> fitCenter
>
> Scales the image to fit inside the view, while maintaining the image
>   aspect ratio. At least one axis will exactly match the view, and the
>   result is centered inside the view.
>
> fitStart
>
> Same as fitCenter but aligned to the top left of the view.
>
> fitEnd
>
> Same as fitCenter but aligned to the bottom right of the view.
>
> fitXY
>
> Scales the x and y dimensions to exactly match the view size; does not
>   maintain the image aspect ratio.

As you can see, **all scale types except `center` rescale the image**.

**My first question:**

Why should I provide so many different resolutions, if the image view rescales the image anyway?

**My second question:**

I could use the `drawable-nodpi` folder for any image, and then use a scale type like `fitCenter`, so that the images will always have the right size. Why should I use any folder except of `drawable-nodpi`?

Comment: If you don't provide any scaleMode, the image is **cropped**. Try putting your images in `drawable-nodpi` and see what happens at different screen densities.

Comment: What exactly does "cropped" mean? Is it similar to the "centerCrop" scale mode?

Comment: Scaling happens because of different screen sizes. Multiple drawable folders are there for different screen resolutions.

Comment: "cropped" means cut. and **not** centered. Cut at the size of the ImageView, starting from the top-left corner.

Comment: "Multiple drawable folders are there for different screen resolutions." ---------------------------- Please try to answer my specific questions, I want to know why I should to use these folders although the images are rescaled anyway because of the scale modes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different resource folders mostly are used for the icons, because for them is most cases scale will cause blur and it allows to help with next issues:

1. After scaling the icon with scale factor like 1,5 the icon might
   looks very blurred.
2. It allows you to use simple images (with less details) for low resolution devices. You can draw much more on icon 72x72 than 24x24.
3. Also providing images in different resolutions allows you to setup
   ImageViews with wrap_content sizes, without calculating the exact
   size in dps.

I use for almost all content only the high resolution resources for the xx-hdpi folder, android will automatically scale it for ldpi, hdpi, mdpi and so on. So for example when you use icon from xx-hdpi folder on hdpi device it will be scaled down twice. You can find more information here: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

And only for icons I use different resolution folders.

Comment: Why should I setup ImageViews with wrap_content? I thought I can declare the height and width in `dp` without any issues.

Comment: Because when the image view will scale the icon you will get something like this: http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_4/material_ext_publish/0Bx4BSt6jniD7c2ZJUFZsUVBrRUk/style_icons_system_best_dont6.png . To prevent your icons from blur the size of image view must match the size of icon without scaling. The easiest way to do it is to put your icons in the resolution depends folder and set sizr of image view to wrap its content.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use `wrap_content` for all `ImageView`s? Since the advantage of an declared size is that I can control exactly how large the image appears on all devices.

Comment: For resources images it is good practice to prepare the right size of them and put them in the right folder and use `wrap_content`. Usually, it is enough to prepare only xx-hdpi images and put them in the xx-hpi folder, system will downscale them if needed.  You should use size in `dp` for `ImageView` and scale factor for images that come not from your resources. Since thay might have various size.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now I got an idea of it. This information was not clear enough in the documentation :) I have one last question: When should I use the nodpi-folder? Should I use it for all ImageViews, that are not setup with wrap_content?

Answer (score 2):

It's a matter of screen density or dpi (dots per inch); It's the number of pixels within a certain area on the screen.

In general if you're a beginner you can get rid of those folders and use just one (`drawable`), no problem, but it is preferable to use the different `drawable` and `mipmap` folders properly in order to make a quality Android app that would look great in different devices with different screen sizes.

Now to sum things up, the ImageView.ScaleType only sets the bounds of the resource to fit the bounds of the view while using the different `drawable` folders allows Android to choose the close resources with the best density for our device which results in better looks for our app.

Read more about this topic in this [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and this [blog](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android).

Comment: I had big issues using `drawable`, because my images were unnecessarily scaled up on nearly all devices. However, when I use `drawable-xhdpi` as the only folder, I have no problems. So it seems that `drawable` should be only used for low end devices?

Comment: That would depend on the resource itself because Android will force scale it to fit in your app.

Comment: Android already force scales it when I define a scale type for my ImageView. Why do the different drawable folders still matter, although the image is rescaled anyway?

Comment: The bigger the difference in densities between the resource and the device's screen the more chubby the look for the app gets. Try it yourself. And read this [article](http://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/understanding-density-independence-in-android), it's pretty useful.